# Why does a double pointer argument have to be declared as single pointer an passed as &var to the function?

Tags: c, pcap, pointer-to-pointer

Why does a double pointer argument have to be declared as a single pointer and passed as &var to the function?

I was wondering why I can't just declare a double pointer then pass it to a function, instead I first have to declare the pointer being pointed at before passing the double pointer.

This is shown for example when I run the argument `**alldevsp` I have to declare it as pointer and then pass its address to the function:

```
pcap_if_t *dvs;
int a = pcap_findalldevs(&dvs, errbuf);
```

However if I declare a pointer to a pointer like so:

```
pcap_if_t **dvs;
int a = pcap_findalldevs(dvs, errbuf);
```

It returns:

```
warning: ‘dvs’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was just wondering why declaring a variable as `**var` and passing it to a function does not work if I do not declare the pointer being pointed at beforehand.

Comment: because `*var` doesn't have the same type anymore, thus is handled by the compiler differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library wants a pointer to a pointer so that it can write into your pointer.

That means that your program needs *allocated memory for the pointer*.

The first example works because `pcap_if_t *dvs;` reserves some memory on the stack for a pointer. Then you pass the *address* of that memory into the `pcap_findalldevs` function.

The second version fails because `pcap_if_t **dvs` does not point to real memory anywhere. The compiler even warns you about it being uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Because `alldevsp` is an [output parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters), that is a parameter that will be used to return a value from a function (`pcap_findalldevs`) to the caller (your code).

In order to achieve that, the parameter should be passed [by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) and since there is no such thing as reference in C, a pointer is used.

To summarize: the library uses the pointer that you've provided to know where to write the data that's why you need to pass a pointer to an **already existing** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to pass a pointer to *something* and that something is `dvs` which has type `pcap_if_t*`.  The type of that pointer is `pcap_if_t**`.  When you delare `pcap_if_t** dvs`, and pass `&dvs`, you are passing a `pcap_if_t***`, which is not the expected type.

If you had:

```
pcap_if_t **dvs;
int a = pcap_findalldevs(dvs, errbuf);
```

Then `dvs` would have the expected type but would point to noting valid (unitialised).

For `pcap_findalldevs()` specifically, the function *modifies* the value of `dvs`, for that to happen, it must have a pointer to it, not just a copy of it - modifying the copy will not result in `dvs` being modified - it must be done by reference.